# While loop is executing one time more as expected

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class fibonacci
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a=0,b=1,c=2;
        while(a<4000000)
        {
            a=b;
            b=c;
            c=a+b;
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }   
}
```

Trying to print Fibonacci series less than 400000, but it is printing 5702887 as well.

Comment: Because you are incrementing `a, b, c` before printing?

Comment: Mathematically, Fibonacci sequence starts like this: `1, 1, 2, 3...`. But from the programmers perspective sequence starts with zero: `0, 1, 1, 2, 3`... I'd recommend you to take a few minutes and read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/)

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange the printing and the checking, so that both act on the same value

```
int a=1,b=1,c=2;
while(a<4000000)
{
    System.out.println(a);
    a=b;
    b=c;
    c=a+b;        
}
```

This outputs the fibonacci sequene, with two times "1" at the start.
If you want "1, 2, 3..." use

```
int a=1,b=2,c=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fibonacci series start from 1. look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451170/in-the-fibonacci-sequence-is-fib0-0-or-1). I gave solution for your code.
You set `a=b` after check `a<4000000`. then you need to check with b.

```
int a=0,b=1,c=2;
    while(b<4000000)
    {
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: its depend on from whre i want to print

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine all you have to do is to put the print statement before calculating the next number **because `3524578 <5702887`**

Comment: Please highlight the addtional insight of this answer, in comparision to the other answers, especially the one already proposing printing before checking (which admittedly is mine). You might want to mention the different behaviour, apparent in the additional "0" which will be printed by your proposal and refer to a definition of the fibonacci sequence which includes that additional initial number. A discussion of the start of the sequence intended by OP (fibonacci or not) might help understanding the consequences.