# Sum of the first n fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program to find the sum of the first N fibonacci numbers but it returned an UnboundLocalError

```
def fib_list(x):
 if x == 1:
    li = [1]
 if x == 2:
    li = [1,2]
 else:
    num1 = li[-1]
    num2 = li[-2]
    li = [1,2]
    for n in range(2,x):
     li.append(num1+num2)
 return li

def fib_sum(x):
 sum = 0
 listy = fib_list(x)
 for n in listy:
    sum += n
 return sum

print("You want the sum of how many fib numbers?")
num = int(input())
print(fib_sum(num))
```

Comment: write this `li = [1,2]` as first statement is `else` your logic also wrong you not updating `num1` and `num2`

Comment: and start values should be `[1, 1`] not `[1, 2]`. you are making simple program very complicated with your incorrect logic

Comment: @HeapOverflow this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/29337929/9050514

Comment: @deadshot thanks for going through my code. Sorry if i wasn't clear earlier. though the num1 and num2 doesn't get updated directly, after each iteration in range(2, x) the list has 1 more item in it(gets appended) and so num1 and num2 gets updated indirectly. The error im getting is UnboundLocalError and I cant find where I got my code wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: see my first comment

Comment: @deadshot If you agree with that answer, which says "starting with 0 totally arbitrary. Why not start with -1 and go -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2...?", then why did you say "should be [1,1] not [1,2]"?

Comment: @HeapOverflow OP just want to find sum so zero doesn't matter even if we consider

Comment: @deadshot It matters because including zero *excludes* another (e.g., sum([0, 1, 1]) vs sum([1, 1, 2]).

Comment: @HeapOverflow it' based on implementation if you consider zero as first number then it differs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- The error is caused by `num1 = li[-1]`: at that time you have not given `li` a value yet (except in the erroneous case where `x` is 1).
- The inner loop does not modify `num1` or `num2`, so you would keep adding the same values. Combined with the first issue, you should move the assignments to `num1` and `num2` into the loop.
- The first two Fibonacci numbers are not 1 and 2, but 0 and 1. So initialise with `li = [0, 1]`. See also [In the Fibonacci sequence, is fib(0) 0 or 1 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451170/in-the-fibonacci-sequence-is-fib0-0-or-1)
- When `x` is 1, the execution also continues into the `else` block. If you change the second `if` with `elif` this will not happen.
- You should probably also deal with the case when `x` is 0.

Taking all that together you get:

```
def fib_list(x):
    if x == 0:
        li = []
    elif x == 1:
        li = [0]
    elif x == 2:
        li = [0,1]
    else:
        li = [0,1]
        for n in range(2,x):
            num1 = li[-1]
            num2 = li[-2]
            li.append(num1+num2)
    return li
```

It is of course possible to write this more succinctly:

```
def fib_list(x):
    li = [0,1]
    if x <= 2:
        return li[:x]
    for n in range(x-2):
        li.append(sum(li[-2:]))
    return li
```

And when you consider that you *only* need the sum, there is no reason to actually build a list:

```
def fib_sum(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 0
    a = 0
    b = total = 1
    for n in range(x-2):
        a, b = b, a + b 
        total += b
    return total
```

The results are as expected:

```
 x | sum | Fib
---+-----+-----------------
 0 |   0 | []
 1 |   0 | [0]
 2 |   1 | [0,1]
 3 |   2 | [0,1,1]
 4 |   4 | [0,1,1,2]
 5 |   7 | [0,1,1,2,3]
 6 |  12 | [0,1,1,2,3,5]
 7 |  20 | [0,1,1,2,3,5,8]
 8 |  33 | [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
```

Comment: Thanks alot my problem has been completely solved :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator function for Fibonacci numbers, which for large inputs performs better than appending to a list. The sum function can be easily made using the generator.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    x, y = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield x
        x, y = y, x + y

def fib_sum(n):
    return sum(fibonacci(n))

print("You want the sum of how many fib numbers?")
num = int(input())
print(fib_sum(num))
```

When run, with an input of `6`, this outputs:

```
You want the sum of how many fib numbers?
6
12
```

Comment: As im still learning I havent come across the generator yet, but I will definitely try this method after I learn it. Thanks for your time :)